# ArrayAdapter with Json Parsing

Tags: java, android, json, xml, android-studio

i'm doing a system of news feed, so, i've a difficulty for adapter my ArrayAdapter insert value into ListView, with: "username, name, picture, content and others values" i'm newbie in Android Studio.

Searching the internet I found this function

```
                HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();

            persons.put(TAG_ID,id);
            persons.put(TAG_NAME,name);
            persons.put(TAG_ADD,address);

            personList.add(persons);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, personList, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_NAME,TAG_ADD},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.address}
        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But, i use ArrayList and ArrayAdapter:

```
ArrayList<Post> postList =
                    new JsonConverter<Post>().toArrayList(s, Post.class);

            ArrayList<String> postador = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(Post value: postList){
                postador.add(value.id_postador);
                postador.add(value.post_legenda);
                if(value.post_foto != null) {
                    postador.add(value.post_foto);
                }
                postador.add(value.post_data);
                postador.add(value.curtidas);

            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, postador
                    );

            lvPost.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I tried it, but no success.

```
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    R.layout.list_item, postador, new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_NAME,TAG_ADD},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.address}
                    );
```

There a method convert ListAdapter in ArrayAdapter or adapter my ArrayAdapter for ListAdapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a newbie to Android, I would like to recommend few things to you.

**1).** Start Using [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) from the very beginning instead of ListView. It is more advanced, flexible and efficient version of ListView. You can find a sample demo for the RecyclerView [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465) and [here](http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example)

**2).** If you still want to use ListView. Then you further have two options, either to use [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) or [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

**a).** Base Adapter as the name suggests, is a base class for all the adapters. If you need more flexibility, you can go with it. You can find the demo sample [here](http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/) and [here](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/)

**b).** On the other hand, ArrayAdapter is a concrete BaseAdapter that is backed by an array of arbitrary objects. By default this class expects that the provided resource id references a single TextView.If you want to use a more complex layout, use the constructors that also takes a field id. That field id should reference a TextView in the larger layout resource.To use something other than TextViews (like in your case) for the array display, for instance, ImageViews, or to have some of data besides `toString()` results fill the views, override `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)` to return the type of view you want. You can find the demo sample [here](http://theopentutorials.com/post/uncategorized/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/) and [here](https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/).

Hope it will help you in future and also I suppose you will get answer to your question in the specified demo samples. Thanks and have a good day.. :)

Comment: Thank you, this method solved my problem.
I had problems to understand this method, but then after i had success.

Comment: Haha, thanks! This is the result of my project, an ealier version. [link](http://i.imgur.com/nWS4iut.jpg) But there're a method of change the background of the cardview for white?